# Check to see if frozen set is a subset of list and the index of every element that is a subset

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, frozenset

I have a bunch of `frozensets` and they are all subsets of a list. What I want to find out is the position of each element of the frozen set in the list.

for e.g.:

```
a = frozenset([1])
b = frozenset([2, 3])
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Now I already know the frozensets are a subset of the list `l`.

What I want is the index position of items in the list i.e. when I am checking for `a`, the function should return the index position for `1` in the list `l` i.e. `[0]`.

Similarly for `b`, it should first return `[1, 2]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already know `a` and `b` are subsets, just use a list comprehension to gather indices of values that are members; use the [`enumerate()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to supply the indices:

```
result = [i for i, v in enumerate(l) if v in subset]
```

where `subset` is one of your `frozenset` instances.

Demo:

```
>>> a = frozenset([1])
>>> b = frozenset([2, 3])
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [i for i, v in enumerate(l) if v in a]
[0]
>>> [i for i, v in enumerate(l) if v in b]
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

If `l` is constant and its items are hashable (they have to be if they are members of a set), then why not make an index:

```
idx = {v:i for i,v in enumerate(l)}
```

This might have problems if `l` has duplicates (`len(l)!=len(set(l))`).

then the function that returns the set of indexes from the set of values is:

```
def indexes(S):
    return set(idx[v] for v in S)
```

This returns a set rather than a list because the order of the set S is undefined so the order of the list of indexes is also undefined so rather than use a list and imply an order that does not exist, use a set.